# How do I create a JSON Array?

Tags: jquery, json, arrays

Hi I want to create a JSON array.

I have tried using:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
  while(itr.hasNext()){
    int objId = itr.next();
jArray.put(objId, odao.getObjectName(objId));
  }
results = jArray.toString();
```

Note: `odao.getObjectName(objId)` retrieves a name based on the "object Id" which is called objId.

However I get a very funny looking array like

```
[null,null,null,"SomeValue",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"AnotherValue",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"SomethingElse","AnotherOne","LastOne"]
```

With only "LastOne" being displayed when I retrieve it using `jQuery`.

The Array SHould look like

> {["3":"SomeValue"],["40":"AnotherValue"],["23":"SomethingElse"],["9":"AnotherOne"],["1":"LastOne"]}

The numbers aren't showing up at all for some reason in the array that I am getting.

Comment: You have a JSON Object of JSON arrays?

Comment: Whatever you get, it shouldn't look like that. Arrays are [foo,bar,baz] while objects are { "foo": "value", "bar": "value", "baz": "value" }. You seem to have your {} and [] confused.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got something from each answer. In the end I realised my question wasn't expressed exactly as it should have been, but your answers solved my problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For your quick Solution:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
   int objId = itr.next();
   json.put(Integer.toString(objId), odao.getObjectName(objId));
   jArray.put(json);
}

results = jArray.toString();
```

Based on [T. J. Crowder's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544119/create-a-json-array-using-java/2544216#2544216), my solution does this:

```
[{"3":"SomeValue"},
 {"40":"AnotherValue"},
 {"23":"SomethingElse"},
 {"9":"AnotherOne"},
 {"1":"LastOne"}
]
```

Refer to Jim Blackler's comment of what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 8):

The clue is in the documentation for JSONArray for method put(int index, String value)

> If the index is greater than the length of the JSONArray, then null elements will be
>   added as necessary to pad it out.

Comment: I see so the index is literally the index of the Array and not some value I can assign.

Comment: @Ankur: Yes, it's an array in the numerically-index-array sense, not a map (aka dictionary aka associative array). You can use JSONObject (http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) for a map; the keys in JSON objects are always strings, so you'll need to make a string out of your `objId`, but that's easy enough.

Answer (score 2):

What you've quoted for your "The object should look like" is invalid JSON. It's an object (delimited by `{` and `}`) but then it has values within it that don't have any keys. See [json.org](http://json.org) for the syntax of JSON.

If you want this:

```
{"3":"SomeValue",
 "40":"AnotherValue",
 "23":"SomethingElse",
 "9":"AnotherOne",
 "1":"LastOne"
}
```

...use [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) instead, and turn your `objId`s into keys when putting the entries in, e.g.:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    int objId = itr.next();
    obj.put(String.valueOf(objId), odao.getObjectName(objId));
}
results = obj.toString();
```

If you want this:

```
[{"3":"SomeValue"},
 {"40":"AnotherValue"},
 {"23":"SomethingElse"},
 {"9":"AnotherOne"},
 {"1":"LastOne"}
]
```

...see [The Elite Gentleman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544119/create-a-json-array-using-java/2544198#2544198) (that's a JSONArray of JSONObjects).

Comment: Until we know what he/she really wants, every answer here is correct.