# Create a JSONArray in Java

Tags: java, android, json

How can I create a JSONArray, since creating a JSONObject is quite simple:

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
j.put("key",value);
```

Right now I can put another string in the JSONObject, or a string representation of a JSONObject.

But how can I create a JSONArray and insert it to the JSONObject?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2544198/1472887

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976643/how-to-create-json-array-in-java

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> But how can I create a JSONArray and insert it to the JSONObject?

You can create JSONArray same like you have tried to create JSONObject.

### Creating time:

For example:

```
JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
j.put("key",value);
j.put("array",myArray);
```

### Retrieving time:

you can fetch the value of String or JSONObject or any by their key name. For example:

```
JSONArray myArray = objJson.getJSONArray("array");
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like:

```
String[] data = {"stringone", "stringtwo"};
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(Arrays.toString(data));
```

Or,  create a JSONArray object and use the put method(s) to add any Strings you want. To output the result, just use the toString() method.

Comment: Why are you passing a `List` into constructor of JSONArray?  It should just accept a `String`.

Comment: I was not able to solve my problem by this so I used JSONArray json = new JSONArray(Arrays.toString(array));

Answer (score 6):

Why dont you use Gson library its very easy to convert any object into json array, json object

Download Gson library then use like

```
Gson gson=new Gson();

String json=gson.toJson(object);
```

if Object is of List object it will create json array

Gson gson = new Gson();

```
reverse parsing for array -- 
        listObject = gson.fromJson(json,
                new TypeToken<List<ClassName>>() {
                }.getType());
```

for single object

```
object = gson.fromJson(json, ClassName.class);
```