# How make array json object

Tags: java, json

how do I make such a Json? I use a regular JSONObject and Array Json and don't understand how to create exactly such a Json object

```
        Faker faker = new Faker();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        json.put("lastName", faker.name().lastName());
        json.put("firstName", faker.name().firstName());

        json.put("phoneNumber", faker.phoneNumber());
        json.put("amount", 1001);

        return json;
```

I want to get in such a JSON

```
{
  "pays":[
    {
      "lastName": "Kek",
      "firstName": "lol",
      "phoneNumber": 4325454555,
      "amount": 1000
    },
    {
      "lastName": "Alex",
      "firstName": "Lol",
      "phoneNumber": 9170067401,
      "amount": 1000
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Seems about right. What's the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to generate 5 users of a similar nature in the pay array and all in a JSON object.

Comment: You'll need another `JSONObject` with a `pays` key and a `JSONArray` value

Comment: Probably the root problem is "how to make an array in JSON from Java". Here a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268799/create-a-jsonarray

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268799/create-a-jsonarray)

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

> ```
> Faker faker = new Faker();
> JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
>
> json.put("lastName", faker.name().lastName());
> json.put("firstName", faker.name().firstName());
>
> json.put("phoneNumber", faker.phoneNumber());
> json.put("amount", 1001);
>
> return json;
> ```

Updated Code:

```
Faker faker = new Faker();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

json.put("lastName", faker.name().lastName());
json.put("firstName", faker.name().firstName());

json.put("phoneNumber", faker.phoneNumber());
json.put("amount", 1001);

// updated here
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(json);

JSONObject finalJson = new JSONObject(); 
finalJson.put("pays",jsonArray);

return finalJson;
```