# String Json para ArrayList

Tags: android, json, string

Does anyone know why this does not work on Android?

```
JSONArray jsonList= new JSONArray("[\"a\"]");
```

and

```
JSONArray jsonList= new JSONArray("['a']");
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544119/how-do-i-create-a-json-array

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow alex. This is a professional Q & A site. Please visit [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question. Try to understand the model of this site. You cannot ask a duplicate, low quality, or unclear question and may get minus votes for this, and vice versa.

Comment: sorry, I'm still not very good at English. Now I understand why this site is so good

Comment: your question is not duplicate at all man, please do not accept anything that anyone can tell you, i know your answer if you like add comment beginning by @mmlooloo to tell me to come and answer that. +1 for your question. `think and bravely disagree`